# Populating fact table

Tags: sql, dimension, fact, warehouse

I've a data warehouse for sales, it has 3 dimensions [product,time,store] and a fact table [sales_fact].

Primary key of 'sales_fact' table is made up of all primary keys of dimensions table, dimension tables are all filled up manually now I want to fill 'sales_fact' table with SUM of prices of products stored in a city for a specific month or 3 month period.

How should I sum up prices from product table which are related to a specific month and add it to fact table?

Comment: What granularity is your FACT table? Typically the SUM() is done during the query, if you are storing you sales information at the transaction level

Comment: There should be a system where you are getting the sales from. Use the prices that applied in this system and multiple by the number of sales for a specific month in that system. Your query on your source system will likely have a group by month clause to allow you to do the sum.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that **sum up prices from product table which are related to a specific month**
is a measure, your query can be like below :

```
SELECT DS.City, DT.[Month], SUM(DP.Price)FROM
SalesFact AS S 
LEFT JOIN DimProduct AS DP ON DP.ProductSK=S.ProductSK
LEFT JOIN DimTime AS DT ON DT.DateSK=S.DateSK
LEFT JOIN DimStore AS DS ON DS.StoreSK=S.StoreSK
WHERE [Date condition] --Add your date conditoon
GROUP BY DS.City, DT.[Month]
```

You can use a [view](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_view.asp) for this measure.